# stop an endless function with threading

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

how do you kill an endless function in Python?
I would like the function to execute for 5 seconds and then be stopped, but thread.terminate() doesn't seem to work, I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'terminate'
```

here is the code

```
import threading, time

def endless():
    while True:
        pass

p = threading.Thread(target=endless, name="endless")
p.start()

time.sleep(5)
if p.is_alive():
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```

Comment: The thread object doesn't have a `terminate` method. Use `process` for that. For threads, you need to set a flag so the thread will exit on its own.

Comment: how would i use process? `AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute 'process'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, use `Process` if you want to force terminate the callback function.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
import time

def endless():
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':  # required for windows
    freeze_support()

    p = Process(target=endless)
    p.start()

    time.sleep(5)
    if p.is_alive():
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
```